# For Angular js ui grid remove right and bottom scrolling boarders

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

In Angular js ui rid, how can I remove  vertical and horizontal scrollbars ?

And also for each column heading I am getting a little carrot icon by default, which shows sort ascend, sort descent, Hide column. I want to remove this also from my column headings.

Instead .table-striped which comes by default for ui grid, I want to use .table-bordered. Is there any place to set these parameters to ui grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    enableHorizontalScrollbar : 0,
    enableVerticalScrollbar : 0,
    enableSorting : false,
    enableColumnMenus : false;
```

Answer (score 1):

Good answer from @Asqan answering the first part of your question. For the second part:

*Instead .table-striped which comes by default for ui grid, I want to use .table-bordered. Is there any place to set these parameters to ui grid?*

I'm thinking you mean you want the look in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oxW3JCOxph6CjxNOQ8G5?p=preview) I created.

You can solve these css issues in one of two general ways.

1) Customize the ui-grid css

2) Leave the original ui-grid css then override it in your own css file

I've shows the first option to solve your "stripped" issue and the second option to implement your desired border. *I have done both for example only so you can see both options* - I recommend choosing and using consistently one method or the other.

The ui-grid sets the ".table-striped" look to which you are referring in the css. You can override this either in you own css file or using the [customizer tool](http://ui-grid.info/customizer/) and setting the @rowcoloreven and @rowcolorodd fields to the hex code for white #ffffff. This will update the ui-grid css to contain the below:

```
.ui-grid-row:nth-child(odd) .ui-grid-cell {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-grid-row:nth-child(even) .ui-grid-cell {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

For ".table-bordered" see specifically in the style.css file these added lines

```
.ui-grid-cell {
    border-style: solid;
    border-bottom: 1px #ff0000;
}
```